# How can i get the data-id of a element?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the data-id of the element selected in pop-up.
 i have to show the selection in the grid, whose solution you have provided. but for Database storage i need the ID value of the selection... how can i get and bind the ID in the grid.???

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // declaration
            $("#lognForm").ejDialog(
                {
                    enableModal: true,
                    enableResize: false,
                    width: 291,
                    close: "onDialogClose",
                    containment: ".cols-sample-area",
                    showFooter: true,
                    footerTemplateId: "sample"
                });
          $("#defaultlistbox").ejListView({ dataSource:ej.DataManager({
                url: "http://js.syncfusion.com/ejServices/Wcf/Northwind.svc/", crossDomain: true
            }),
   query: ej.Query().from("Suppliers").select("SupplierID", "ContactName"),
   fieldSettings: { text: "ContactName"},mouseUp: "onmouseup",height:"400px" ,enableCheckMark: true,
            enableFiltering: true,   
  
   });

            $("#btnOpen").ejButton({ size: "medium", "click": "onOpen", type: "button", height: 30, width: 172 });
            $("#Grid").ejGrid({
                columns: [
                        { field: "title", headerText: "ListviewData", width: 80 },
                ]
            });
            $("#btn1").ejButton({ size: "medium", "click": "onbtnOpen", type: "button", height: 30, width: 172 });

        });


        function onOpen() {
            $("#btnOpen").hide();
            $("#lognForm").ejDialog("open");          
        }
       function onbtnOpen(){
            $("#lognForm").ejDialog("close");
        }
        function onDialogClose(args) {
            $("#btnOpen").show();
        }

        function onmouseup(e) {
            var selections = $('#defaultlistbox').ejListView("getCheckedItems");
            var items = [];
            $(selections).each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var item = { title: $this.find("span").html() };
    
            items.push(item);

            });
            if (selections.length > 0) {
                var obj = $("#Grid").ejGrid("instance");
                obj.setModel({ dataSource: items })
               obj.refreshContent(); 
        }  
      else{
         var obj = $("#Grid").ejGrid("instance"); 
        obj.dataSource([]); }
    }

    </script>
```

```html
<li class="e-user-select e-list e-list-check e-state-default" data-id="2">
```

Comment: In jQuery you could just call `.data('id')` on the matched element to get that value.  Did you try that?

Comment: @David: You could, but only if you really want to initialize the jQuery data cache for the element. If you just want the value, `data` is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reference to that javascript DOM object, simply look for the `dataset` property. It's a hashmap containing string keys, that are on your HTML element prefixed with `data`. 
For example, you'll find `data-id` on your object as `myObject.dataset["id"]`.